# OBS can't do window capture under Sway

Tags: wayland, sway, obs-studio

I'm running Fedora Linux with Sway,
and I wanted to capture some stuff with OBS. 
However, there is simply no option to do a "Window capture". 
As far as I can tell, this is usually
attributed to problems with PipeWire or `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`. 
Despite that, I can do a full screen capture – that works via PipeWire,
and to select the monitor it prompts me with a nice window,
which is, presumably, generated by `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`. 
So, I guess, those work just fine:

[image: screenshot showing Screen Capture source selection (?) window]

As suggested in `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr` GitHub repo, I've also added this to my sway config:

```
exec dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd WAYLAND_DISPLAY XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway
```

However, that didn't really help. 
What else can cause OBS to refuse to capture windows?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that sharing of individual windows is not supported yet by `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`. I'm in the same boat as you.

- https://github.com/emersion/xdg-desktop-portal-wlr/wiki/FAQ#will-this-let-me-share-individual-windows
- https://github.com/emersion/xdg-desktop-portal-wlr/issues/107
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wlroots/wlr-protocols/-/issues/93

Comment: If your answer is "this is not possible", it might have been better as a comment, perhaps.

Comment: @number9 the question was "What else can cause OBS to refuse to capture windows?" and this is the answer. answering stuff in comments doesn't help anyone since it can't be edited or voted on.